# Count Instances in Array with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have just started to use Knockout.Js and have struggled a little to achieve what I would consider to be basic things. The most annoying one is trying to get a count of unique instances of strings within an observable array and print to the ui.

Specifically, I have a model of hotels, each with a 'hotelType' field. This would be 'B&B', or 'All-inclusive' etc. I've managed to get a unique list of these hotel types displayed as checkboxes ,and bound them back to an observableArray. This array is then used to filter the list of displayed hotels. What I can't do however, is provide a count of each category type within the array (i.e. 50 hotels, 40 B&B's etc).

The only way that occurs to me is to have new fields built from Compute, and use arrayFilter to get the length of a filtered array. This would be quite expensive and messy though.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe I'd suggest a different approach. I would suggest upgrading `hotelType` from a string to a proper part of your application. For example, you could make it a ViewModel that lives between a `hotel` and your `$root` (or list of hotels). In essence, your list of hotels would then become a grouped list, based on `hotelType`.

The following JSON suggests the structure I'm talking about:

```
var data = {
    allHotels : [{
          hotelType : "B&B",
          hotels : [{name: "West Inn", chosen: false}, 
                    {name: "East Inn", chosen: true}]
        },{
          hotelType : "All-inclusive",
          hotels : [{name: "North Inn", chosen: false}, 
                    {name: "Center Inn", chosen: false}, 
                    {name: "South Inn", chosen: false}]
    }]};
```

This will make it very easy to have a count on the number of hotels per type. It would be something like this in your View:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: allHotels">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: hotelType"></span>
        (<span data-bind="text: hotels().length"></span>)
        ...foreach: hotels here...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGJet/) for a demo of what I'm suggesting.

The total number of hotels is also easy: the sum of all totals for hotelTypes. The totals are updated just when it's needed: if an item's removed/added from a relevant collection.